# Surveys on Navier Stokes Equations and its physical implications

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, reference-request

Hi,

I'm a beginning graduate student, and I'm interested in learning more about Fluid Mechanics and, in particular, the Navier stokes Equations. I would like to know: are there are some sort of free survey articles (available online) that discuss the problem?  Also, I would like to know if there are any articles that discuss the the possible physical implications of the solutions (assuming it is answered affirmatively).

Thanks,
Bharadwaj

Comment: Why not a book on fluid dynamics if you really want a physical understanding of Navier-Stokes and its solutions?  D.J. Acheson's book is a decent introduction.

Comment: I second jc's comment on Acheson.

Answer (score 6):

Terry Tao wrote a blog article a few years ago:

[Why global regularity for Navier-Stokes is hard](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/03/18/why-global-regularity-for-navier-stokes-is-hard/)

and another which followed up on some aspects (and links through to an arxiv preprint too): 

[A quantitative formulation of the global regularity problem for the periodic Navier-Stokes equation](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/a-quantitative-formulation-of-the-global-regularity-problem-for-the-periodic-navier-stokes-equation/)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know about it, this is one of Clay Math's Millennium Problems, http://claymath.org/millennium/Navier-Stokes_Equations/.  They have a brief review with some citations that may be useful.  The website claims there's a video of a lecture on it, too, but I haven't watched it so I do not know how useful it would be.

Answer (score 1):

See [Roger Temam's review](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=NAF6W1oN9pcC).

Comment: I made a link to a book.  I hope it was the right one.

Comment: Yes, it is a good book and somehow necessary for researchers of NS-Eq. Temam also has an article name:some developments on Navier-Stokes equations in the second half of 20th century. Although this is written in ten years ago, it is of great value. Anyhow, we did not cover a long distance in these ten years.   Another book worth reading is Recent developments in the Navier-Stokes problem (P G Lemarié-Rieusset), using harmonica analysis method.